# RecyclerView - DefaultItemAnimator not animating add

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use DefaultItemAnimator for animating the adding of an item at the end of a RecyclerView. When a new item is added I notify the adapter, and if it is the last one I scroll down to make it appear.

```
_adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
if (position==end) _recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(end);
```

I'm unsuccessful so far to make the animation working, but investigating made me realize why it's not working. Indeed, `animateAdd(holder)` is called as expected and the adding animation is about to start in the DefaultItemAnimator.

But then who shows up? `RecyclerView.removeAndRecycleScrapInt(Recycler)` is called. Ok, that's normal  because a view is reused for the added item. But the problem is that the itemAnimator animation on the corresponding holder is cancelled in this method.

Am I missing something or it this a (known) bug? Important thing is it's working alright if the added item is not inserted at the end.

There's an annoying workaround: delaying the `notifyItemInserted` call by putting inside a `new Handler().post(Runnable)` but not sure it's such a good idea... Doing that means counting on the fact that the item was already added, but not the animation, when `removeAndRecycleScrapInt` is called. And it's not working if I use `postDelay(delay)` with a delay more than a few milliseconds. So it might be working only on some devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I just realize what I was missing... Using **smooth** scrolling delays the call `RecyclerView.removeAndRecycleScrapInt` too much and thus cancels the animation which already started. The key is thus to use normal scrolling:

```
_adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
if (position==end) _recyclerView.scrollToPosition(end);
```